# Linux kernel 4.3 has issue with GPU/graphics hardware

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, graphics

I updated to [linux kernel 4.3 on Debian Jessie via backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/linux-image-686-pae), i.e.

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-686-pae
```

on my 32Bit laptop with physical address extension and now, after booting, the screen remains dark (I use Gnome as provided by debian as desktop environment). Upon a virtual terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+F1`) I executed `dmesg` logs which contains several times entries like the following:

```
[   81.112347] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   81.112367] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 29 at /build/linux-5EEdAm/linux-4.3.5/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_atomic.c:491 drm_atomic_check_only+0x48f/0x5f0 [drm]()
[   81.112370] Modules linked in: xt_addrtype ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat bridge stp llc dm_thin_pool ctr dm_persistent_data ccm dm_bio_prison dm_bufio crc32c_generic libcrc32c loop binfmt_misc nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd grace fscache sunrpc xt_tcpudp nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables joydev arc4 rt2800pci rt2800mmio rt2800lib iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support acer_wmi rt2x00pci psmouse sparse_keymap evdev snd_hda_codec_realtek rt2x00mmio rt2x00lib serio_raw snd_hda_codec_generic eeprom_93cx6 lpc_ich coretemp pcspkr mac80211 mfd_core i2c_i801 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211 snd_hda_core crc_ccitt rfkill snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore i915 drm_kms_helper
[   81.112453]  drm wmi battery ac i2c_algo_bit shpchp video button acpi_cpufreq tpm_tis tpm processor fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 sha256_generic hmac drbg ansi_cprng xts gf128mul algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt dm_mod sr_mod cdrom ata_generic sg sd_mod ums_realtek uas usb_storage ahci libahci ata_piix sata_sil24 libata scsi_mod thermal r8169 mii ehci_pci uhci_hcd ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common
[   81.112515] CPU: 0 PID: 29 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G        W       4.3.0-0.bpo.1-686-pae #1 Debian 4.3.5-1~bpo8+1
[   81.112518] Hardware name: MEDION WIM2210/WIM2210, BIOS V1.0E      03/04/2008
[   81.112527] Workqueue: events output_poll_execute [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112531]  00000000 27827003 f764dbc0 c12ad425 00000000 c1067341 c161ae90 00000000
[   81.112540]  0000001d f85b0890 000001eb f859eadf 00000009 000001eb f859eadf f39d6000
[   81.112549]  00000000 f0c78ea0 f764dbd0 c1067442 00000009 00000000 f764dc20 f859eadf
[   81.112557] Call Trace:
[   81.112566]  [<c12ad425>] ? dump_stack+0x3e/0x59
[   81.112572]  [<c1067341>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x91/0xc0
[   81.112582]  [<f859eadf>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x48f/0x5f0 [drm]
[   81.112591]  [<f859eadf>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x48f/0x5f0 [drm]
[   81.112596]  [<c1067442>] ? warn_slowpath_null+0x22/0x30
[   81.112605]  [<f859eadf>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x48f/0x5f0 [drm]
[   81.112614]  [<f859ddfa>] ? drm_atomic_set_crtc_for_plane+0x6a/0x100 [drm]
[   81.112623]  [<f859ed28>] ? drm_atomic_set_fb_for_plane+0x28/0xa0 [drm]
[   81.112632]  [<f859ec56>] ? drm_atomic_commit+0x16/0x60 [drm]
[   81.112661]  [<f88579e1>] ? intel_get_load_detect_pipe+0x421/0x5f0 [i915]
[   81.112667]  [<c1096f72>] ? put_prev_entity+0x32/0xb00
[   81.112691]  [<f888f52a>] ? intel_tv_detect+0x10a/0x5e0 [i915]
[   81.112702]  [<f8597e50>] ? drm_get_edid+0x30/0x3d0 [drm]
[   81.112711]  [<f866fb3b>] ? drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x27b/0x4a0 [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112717]  [<c12b09b2>] ? kobject_uevent_env+0x162/0x560
[   81.112724]  [<f866fd77>] ? drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x17/0x20 [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112730]  [<f8679e51>] ? drm_fb_helper_probe_connector_modes.isra.3+0x41/0x60 [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112736]  [<f867b117>] ? drm_fb_helper_hotplug_event+0x57/0xd0 [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112743]  [<f866f601>] ? drm_kms_helper_hotplug_event+0x21/0x30 [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112749]  [<f866ffd8>] ? output_poll_execute+0x188/0x1c0 [drm_kms_helper]
[   81.112754]  [<c107dc1b>] ? process_one_work+0x11b/0x390
[   81.112759]  [<c107e569>] ? worker_thread+0x49/0x450
[   81.112762]  [<c107e520>] ? rescuer_thread+0x2c0/0x2c0
[   81.112767]  [<c1082e13>] ? kthread+0xb3/0xd0
[   81.112772]  [<c1538301>] ? ret_from_kernel_thread+0x21/0x30
[   81.112776]  [<c1082d60>] ? kthread_park+0x50/0x50
[   81.112780] ---[ end trace fc917999298a0344 ]---
```

As this seems to be a GPU/graphics related failure here some ome hardware information gathered using `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Medion WIM 2210 Notebook PC [MD96850]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 48
    Region 0: Memory at fc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
            Address: fee0300c  Data: 4172
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
            Bridge: PM- B3+
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Wistron Corp. Medion WIM 2210 Notebook PC [MD96850]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fc100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
            Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
            Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
            Bridge: PM- B3+
```

**Can anybody relate or has had similar issues?** I am somewhat helpless since I don't know anything about anything regarding hardware problems, linux kernel and related topics.

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe there's in issue with your graphics card? Maybe your card uses an proprietary BIOS or something like this? There seems to be a problem with a GPU driver, somehow connected to DRM: `[   81.112367] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 29 at /build/linux-5EEdAm/linux-4.3.5/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_atomic.c:491`

Comment: Yeah, seems to be. I updated the post and added some hardware information, but don't know much more on how to solve the problems now. @mnille, would be nice if you could have a look again.